# Mount Raid5 Array made in bios then formatted in Windows

Tags: mount, raid, disk, dmraid

I have created a Raid5 array in my bios, using the intel chipset, with 3 of my drives. I have formatted the drive in Windows 10 and can confirm that the raid array is working fine. I then installed dmraid in order to mount the array in Ubuntu, but the raid array is not appearing in nautilus to be mounted.

Here is my output from lsblk:

```
NAME                                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                     8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array (dm-0)    252:0    0   1.5T  0 dmraid 
  └─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   128M  0 part   
sdb                                     8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk   
├─sdb1                                  8:17   0   450M  0 part   
├─sdb2                                  8:18   0   100M  0 part   
├─sdb3                                  8:19   0    16M  0 part   
└─sdb4                                  8:20   0   223G  0 part   
sdc                                     8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk   
├─sdc1                                  8:33   0   128M  0 part   
└─sdc2                                  8:34   0   2.7T  0 part   /mnt/Data
sdd                                     8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array (dm-0)    252:0    0   1.5T  0 dmraid 
  └─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   128M  0 part   
sde                                     8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk   
├─sde1                                  8:65   0   128M  0 part   
└─sde2                                  8:66   0 931.4G  0 part   /mnt/Data2
sdf                                     8:80   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array (dm-0)    252:0    0   1.5T  0 dmraid 
  └─isw_cffajgfadh_Raid5Array1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   128M  0 part   
sdg                                     8:96   0  59.6G  0 disk   
├─sdg1                                  8:97   0  43.7G  0 part   /
├─sdg2                                  8:98   0     1K  0 part   
└─sdg5                                  8:101  0  15.9G  0 part   [SWAP]
sdh                                     8:112  0 931.5G  0 disk   
├─sdh1                                  8:113  0 915.6G  0 part   
├─sdh2                                  8:114  0     1K  0 part   
└─sdh5                                  8:117  0  15.9G  0 part
```

So it appears that dmraid is doing something with the raid, but it is in a state where it cant be mounted. Any suggestions, thanks in advance.